# Issue in using arrays as parameters of method of PHP custom class

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

To explain my issue, here is a simple code at first:

```
public function sql($data) {
  if (is_array($data)) {
    $cells    = $data['cells'];
    $from     = $data['from'];
    $where    = $data['where'];
    $joins    = $data['joins'];
    $order_by = $data['order_by'];
    $o_type   = $data['order_by_type'];
    $limit    = $data['limit'];
    /*****************************/

    if ($cells == '') { $cells = "*"; }
    if ($where != '') { $where = "where ".$where; }
    if ($oredr_by != '') { $order_by = "order by ".$order_by." ".$o_type; }
    if ($limit != '') { $limit = "limit ".$limit; }
    //
    $sql = "select ".$cells." from ".$from." ".$joins." ".$where." ".$order_by." ".$limit;
    $run = mysqli_query($_SESSION['con'], $sql);
  }else{
    $run = mysqli_query($_SESSION['con'], $data);
  }
}
```

When I start using this method, I pass a multidimensional array as a parameter, like this:

```
$sql = $class->sql([ "from" => "table", "order_by" => "id", "order_by_type" => "asc" ]);
/* This will generate and run this query: select * from table order by id asc */
// Notice that I've only used 3 keys, not the all above.
```

In `Apache server`, it works OK perfectly when I just use some of the `keys` of array, but in `XAMPP` it doesn't because it says that I have to pass all the `parameters` `(cells, from, where, joins, ...)` even if they are `empty`.

Please help me to resolve this, and thanks.

Comment: This will be difference in the error_reporting level of your php settings. In your apache it will not be that strict as it is in your xampp.

Comment: OK that's clear like sunrise. But could you guide me how to solve it if my host in internet is XAMPP? How to avoid this issue? You know, a huge class, a lot of methods.

Comment: @nael_d : Change `$from` to `$table`, you have not `$table` variable

Comment: Changed. It's my fault from speed typing. This is not my issue at all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isset` to check if an array key is present, then get it's value like.

```
public function sql($data) {
  if (is_array($data)) {
    $cells = '';
    if(isset($data['cells']) {
       $cells = $data['cells'];
    }

    ....
/*****************************/

if ($cells == '') { $cells = "*"; }
if ($where != '') { $where = "where ".$where; }
if ($oredrby != '') { $orderby = "order by ".$orderby." ".$od_type; }
if ($limit != '') { $limit = "limit ".$limit; }
  $sql = "select ".$cells." from ".$table." ".$joins." ".$where." ".$orderby." ".$limit;
  $run = mysqli_query($_SESSION['con'], $sql);
}else{
  $run = mysqli_query($_SESSION['con'], $data);
}
}
```

Or simply just do `error_reporting(1)` before calling this function or in your index.php.

Comment: That works with me. Thanks !! :-) But Does it work if I used this way `$cells = $data['cells'] = "*";` ? I mean: Will they accept my parameters puts the different values if I didn't pass anything?

Comment: no problem.. what you are asking will simply assign `"*"` to $cells and $data['cells']..  You could look into using a ternary operator for that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this.

```
$arr = ["a"];
echo $arr["b"];
```

You will get an error notice.

```
Notice: Undefined index: b
```

If you want to avoid this use it in this way.

```
$arr = ["a"];
$arr = ["b"] = "";
echo $arr["b"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$from` to `$table`, you have not `$table` variable

```
$from    = $data['from'];
```

to

```
$table    = $data['from'];
```

Also you have spelling mistake biggest spelling mistake which is very difficult to find.`orderby` and `oredrby`

Comment: Done. Sorry I didn't mean it. It's from speed typing.

Comment: @nael_d : Also you have spelling mistake biggest spelling mistake which is very difficult to find.`orderby` and `oredrby`

Comment: I know I'm sorry, I've written them immediately just to explain my issue. The original code is very similar to this but corrected and verified well.